# Logrotate not removing the logs

Tags: linux, bash, logging, log-files, logrotate

I have the following logrotate script

```
/path/to/folder/*.logs {
   daily
   rotate 30
   notifempty
   sharedscripts
   copytruncate
   compress
   dateext


   preremove
     if file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q gzip$; then
          mkdir -p /path/to/archive/folder && cp $1 $_
     fi
   endscript
}
```

---

- What I am trying to achieve:-

  *Before removal of a log file after a retention of 30 days, copy to another folder.*

I am running this logstash config on debug mode

```
logrotate -d $CONFIG_FILE
```

By the looks of the logs, the rotation is working fine, but it does not even run the `preremove` script. 
I have not run this config on live yet, as I wanted to test it before doing that.

> logrotate version 3.8.6

Comment: The first line should have names of log files, not the name of a directory. Is the rotation perhaps being done by some other stanza? That would explain why the `preremove` script is not being run.

Comment: running on the debug mode, I can see the rotation is being done within this block. 
It also removes the old log files. But it does not seem to be running the `preremove` block

Comment: You use `logstash` to test `logrotate`? Try to set the file, as @wurtel mentioned, never seen logrotate on directories. Your line `if file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q gzip$; then` tests for the file, too.

Comment: @Lenniey - apologies, typo in the question. sorry. `logrotate -d $CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: @Lenniey used a `/path/to/folder/*.logs`. Still not working

Comment: @Lenniey -if file --mime-type "$1" | grep -q gzip$; then- I check if the file to be removed is compressed. I agree this is not necessary here since I am not using a delayed compression and a rotation period of 30 days.

Comment: @wurtel - added the first line. Still does not seem to be working. 
Does it maybe have to do something with running ~preremove~ on just debug mode?

Comment: `-d, --debug               Don't do anything, just test (implies -v)`. Test it using `-v` without `-d`.

Comment: Also, don't crosspost, either it's a SF question or a SU question. https://superuser.com/questions/1430822/logrotate-not-removing-log-files

Comment: @Lenniey What I am trying to achieve here it so dry run this script, before replacing the current script that does not have the `preremove` with this script that has `preremove`

Comment: @Lenniey, Also, `-d` implies `-v`. From https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92989/discussion-between-rpt-and-lenniey).